# Convert Get to Post on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is original code below.
New 'result.html' file can not read Get request anymore. It only read POST.
So, I have to convert the method from GET to POST.

**JS**

```html
<script>
function sendData(v_uid, v_name, v_address) {
    window.open('./result.html?uid='+v_uid+'&name='+v_name+'&address='+v_address+'', 'room1', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=no');
}
</script>

<button type="button" onClick="sendData('uid','name','address')">Send Data</button>
```

Comment: You can check the official MDN documentation about how to perform a POST request in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST

Comment: `I have code to send data through Get method` - which is it?

Comment: @choz I guess he means that the window.open is doing that.

Comment: @briosheje I mean I have this code now. and I have to change it to send through POST.

Comment: Are you not able to create a hidden div with a form and then serialise the form before sending. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData